# Adding new fields to an existing table, inserting data into proper position, then joining

Tags: sql

**Scenario One**
I have two new fields that I want to add to a table called existingTable. After I add these fields, I can update SOME but NOT ALL records with data for those fields. There will be blank entries, and I am fine with this.

**Problem One**
I want to make sure that the CORRECT records are updated. The primary key for the existing table and the incoming data table is Email.

**Proposed Solution One**
An UPDATE query looking like this is the solution.

UPDATE existingTable
SET existingTable.newField1 = incomingDataTable.newField1, existingTable.newField2 = incomingDataTable.newField2
WHERE existingTable.Email = incomingDataTable.Email

What do you think?

---

**Scenario Two**
After the table is updated with the new fields & data in the proper records, I want to join this table with two other ones. I want ALL entries, even if some fields are blank, to be in this join. I don't want ANY records excluded.

By the way, each record in these tables has a 1-to-1 relationship with its partner in the other tables. There SHOULD NOT BE ANY duplicate records. In the past, I've seen Access use an INNER JOIN, which excludes records that do not have values for newField1 and newField2. This is not what I want.

**Problem**
I'm inexperienced at joining tables. The different joins are a bit confusing to me.

**Proposed Solution**
Does the join I use necessarily matter since the three to-be-joined tables should have a one-to-one relationship?

SELECT * FROM existingTable
FULL JOIN tableToJoinWith1, tableToJoinWith2
On existingTable.Email = tableToJoinWith1.Email, tableToJoinWith1.Email = tableToJoiNWith2.Email

Answer (score 0):

Clarifying your Scenario 2. I'm assuming you mean you want all the rows from `existingTable` even if there is no match on the `Email` field with either of the other tables. In this case, a `LEFT JOIN` is what you want:

```
SELECT * FROM existingTable
LEFT JOIN tableToJoinWith1 ON existingTable.email = tableToJoinWith1.email 
LEFT JOIN tableToJoinWith2 ON existingTable.email = tableToJoinWith2.email
```

For scenario 1, the problem is that you haven't given it any sort of SELECT for `incomingDataTable`. In standard SQL, to my knowledge, there's no nice way to do this that supports multiple columns. So it depends what database you're using. Some will let you do this:

```
UPDATE existingTable
SET newField1 = incomingDataTable.newField1, newField2 = incomingDataTable.newField2 
FROM incomingDataTable
WHERE existingTable.Email = incomingDataTable.Email
```

But some won't. Others will allow this:

```
UPDATE (Select * FROM existingTable JOIN incomingDataTable
ON existingTable.Email = incomingDataTable.Email)
SET existingTable.newField1 = incomingDataTable.newField1,
existingTable.newField2 = incomingDataTable.newField2
```

If it were only a single column, you could do this which is totally standard:

```
UPDATE existingTable SET newField1 = (SELECT newField1 FROM incomingDataTable 
WHERE existingTable.Email = incomingDataTable.Email)
```

Comment: "Clarifying your Scenario 2. I'm assuming you mean you want all the rows from existingTable even if there is no match on the Email field with either of the other tables. In this case, a LEFT JOIN is what you want:" <br/> There's another constraint I forgot to mention. Accidentally, there are a different number of records between these tables even though they should be 1-to-1. Yeah, the important thing is that ALL records in existingTable are shown. I think LEFT JOIN is the right thing. <br/> Thanks for the selects for the scenario 1 response. I think that sounds correct. Trying this out now.

Comment: I had problems using your statements. Here's what I think I can use, based off a test with a small data set:

UPDATE existingTable INNER JOIN incomingDataTable ON existingTable.Email = incomingDataTable.Email SET [existingTable].[newField1] = [incomingDataTable].[newField1], [existingTable].[newField2] = [incomingDatTable].[newField2];

I think that INNER JOIN doesn't cause any problems.